# Sanctification of God

Tags: leviticus, context

In Leviticus 22:32,

> Do not profane my holy name, that I may be sanctified in the midst of
>   the Israelites.

What is the meaning of this verse? does it mean that we can sanctify the LORD through our deeds, and make him more holy so to speak?

The emphasis in the OT always is to make the Israelites more holy (see beginning of chapter 19 leviticus), but in this verse the emphasis is clearly on God and his sanctification. How can we make God more holy?

Answer (score 1):

No, this does not imply we make God holy or more holy. It has a contextual meaning similar to *consecrate*. Or *made sacred* i.e. to *set apart* as holy.

**That is, in context this word means 'acknowledged as holy' or 'be considered holy':**

> **Leviticus 22:32**
>
> ולא תחללו את־ שם קדשי ***ונקדשתי** בתוך בני ישראל אני יהוה מקדשכם
>
> Neither shall you profane My holy name: **but I will be hallowed*** by/among the children of Israel—I am the LORD, who sanctifies you.

* <sup>That is, ***"acknowledged as holy"***</sup>

Thus, when we read in the New Testament a phrase like:

> **1 Peter 3:15**
>
> **Κύριον δὲ τὸν Χριστὸν ἁγιάσατε*** ἐν ταῖς καρδίαις ὑμῶν ἕτοιμοι ἀεὶ πρὸς ἀπολογίαν παντὶ τῷ αἰτοῦντι ὑμᾶς λόγον περὶ τῆς ἐν ὑμῖν ἐλπίδος ἀλλὰ μετὰ πραΰτητος καὶ φόβου
>
> **but sanctify* Christ as Lord** in your hearts; ready always to give an answer in defense of the hope in you: yet with gentleness and reverence.

* <sup>That is, ***revere and set apart from all else Christ as the Lord***</sup>

The meaing becomes more clear: ***revere** or **set apart*** *as holy* (and in context, as the Holy One Himself, God).

---

I think we've lost sight of the original meaning of 'holy', which is set apart for the service of God, or set apart from everything else because of the intrinsic or extrinsic *goodness* of something.

That is, it originally meant good > because apart from and different from everything else.

In the Biblical context, the things or persons set apart (hallowed) was because of some intrinsic or extrinsic goodness.

For example, the Ark of the Covenant was probably one of the most holy objects on earth because it held the very sacred items representative of the Covenant between God and mankind, and because of the presence of God which overshadowed it. Another example is when, becaues God is speaking at the bush to Moses, Moses takes his sandles off because he is standing on what has been made holy by the presence of God.

---

**Thus, YHVH wants people to revere Him as holy ('hallow' Him) because He *is* good and holy, not because He needs to be made holy** (what 'sanctify' would mean for the believer), and that His name not be profaned, nor His sacrafices, nor His commandments broken.